# Explanation for equation 7 in Arjovsky et. al. Invariant Risk Minimization

Tags: regression, invariance

I would like to ask you for a help with understanding equation 7 in theorem 9 in [Arjovsky et. al. Invariant Risk Minimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.02893).
The equation is following:
$$
\Phi\;\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[ X\,X^{\top} \right] \Phi^\top w = \Phi\;\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}\left[ X\,Y \right]
$$
where $X$ is the explaining random variable and $Y$ is the explained variable. $\Phi^\top w$ is a linear predictor, where $\Phi$ is a linear maping from the support of $X$ to some set $\mathcal{H}$ and $w$ is then a linear classifier $w:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{Y}$ with $\mathcal{Y}$ being the support of $Y$.

I know that the equation has something to do with the analytical solution of linear regression
$$\beta = (X^\top X)^{-1}X^{\top}Y$$
but I just somehow can't put the things together...

Please note that Arjovsky et. al. define invariance only in expectation, therefore they look at the expectations only.

Thank you for any help

Comment: There is a proof provided in Section B.3 of the appendix which unpacks the equation. You need to replace $Y$ with the presumed linear predictor as a function of $X$ and the error term.

Comment: The notations are confusing: are $\Phi$ and $\omega$ matrices or functions?

Comment: @Xi'an these are linear functions - linear functions over finite vector spaces can be represented as a matrix, therefore the author switch automatically to matrices

Comment: @psboonstra Thank you. Now I undestand the theorem. If I understand it correctly, the authors try to relate to equation 4 using equation 7: if I solve equation 7, then I minimize $\mathbb{D}_{lin}$ in equation 4?